# Enqueue javascript with type="module"

Tags: javascript, wordpress, es6-modules

I want to use `countUp.js` on my custom theme in Wordpress.

When I add the file with `wp_enqueue_script()`, I get an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

I've read that it can be fixed setting on the `<script>` label *`type="module"`*, but I don't know how to do that, as that option doesn't exist in `wp_enqueue_script()`...

Anyone can hel me?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

One can add attributes to a script by applying filter '[script_loader_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/)'.

Use `add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_type_attribute' , 10, 3);` to add the filter.

Define the callback function like the example given on the link above:

```
function add_type_attribute($tag, $handle, $src) {
    // if not your script, do nothing and return original $tag
    if ( 'your-script-handle' !== $handle ) {
        return $tag;
    }
    // change the script tag by adding type="module" and return it.
    $tag = '<script type="module" src="' . esc_url( $src ) . '"></script>';
    return $tag;
}
```

Comment: do I need to register a handle first? Also, do I then also enqueue the script as normal after?

Comment: @AviG Yes, you do. You can first enqueue your script using `wp_enqueue_script( 'your-script-handle', 'script-file.js' );` and then add the filter using  `add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_type_attribute' , 10, 3);`

Comment: In case you need it, here is the documentation for add_filter as well: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/

Answer (score 5):

The `wp_script_attributes` filter is also handy for this and a little cleaner if all you need to do is add an attribute.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_script_attributes/

```
add_filter( 'wp_script_attributes', 'add_type_attribute', 10, 1 );

function add_type_attribute( $attributes ) {
  // Only do this for a specific script.
  if ( isset( $attributes['id'] ) && $attributes['id'] === 'my-handle-js' ) {
    $attributes['type'] = 'module';
  }

  return $attributes;
}
```

The `id` comes from the handle you set when enqueuing the script. The format being `<handle>-js`. In this case the enqueuing could be something like:

```
wp_enqueue_script(
  'my-handle',
  'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/some/url',
  array(),
  null,
  false
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a little more complicated way to go... But I've used the following to add defer, crossorigin etc...

I don't think it's that official yet but from what I've read it's not a bad way to do it (and I've seen this approach in production for several plugins).

So, (adjust your params/variables to suit obviously) script registering (not just enqueue) is required (see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_script_add_data/):

```php
wp_register_script('countup-js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/countup.js/2.0.0/countUp.min.js', ['jquery'], $js_version, true);
wp_enqueue_script('countup-js');

wp_scripts()->add_data('countup-js', 'type', 'module');
```

And then your filter (like the top answer here, but I think this outlines how you can set it up to be more reusable, flexible etc)

```php
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'moduleTypeScripts', 10, 2);
function moduleTypeScripts($tag, $handle)
{
    $tyype = wp_scripts()->get_data($handle, 'type');

    if ($tyype) {
        $tag = str_replace('src', 'type="' . esc_attr($tyype) . '" src', $tag);
    }

    return $tag;
}
```

Comment: Shout-out to this thread: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/387674/wp-script-add-data-doesnt-seem-to-work

Comment: This adds the `type='module'` to the script while not removing the original `type='text\javascript'`, I added an answer that breaks up the string to do the necessary replacements.

Answer (score 1):

To further add to what @Zeldri said, you don't need to make use of `wp_localize_script()`, we can keep that function for translations as it was first intended for.

Below is the code you'd need if you don't want to lose code added using `wp_add_inline_script()`

```
function make_scripts_modules( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    
            if ( 'your-script-handle' !== $handle ) {
                return $tag;
            }
    
            $id = $handle . '-js';
    
            $parts = explode( '</script>', $tag ); // Break up our string
    
            foreach ( $parts as $key => $part ) {
                if ( false !== strpos( $part, $src ) ) { // Make sure we're only altering the tag for our module script.
                    $parts[ $key ] = '<script type="module" src="' . esc_url( $src ) . '" id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '">';
                }
            }
    
            $tags = implode( '</script>', $parts ); // Bring everything back together
    
            return $tags;
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'make_scripts_modules' , 10, 3);
```

This will turn the required script into a module and leave the inline scripts alone.

Answer (score 1):

To me Peter's answer is simpler, so this corrects the issues that answer has.

```
// enqueue the scripts however you like
wp_register_script('countup-js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/countup.js/2.0.0/countUp.min.js', ['jquery'], $js_version, true);
wp_enqueue_script('countup-js');

// explicitly set the type based on the id
wp_scripts()->add_data('countup-js', 'type', 'module');

// add our function to use the explicitly set type.
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'custom_script_types', 10, 2);
function custom_script_types($tag, $handle) {
    $type = wp_scripts()->get_data($handle, 'type');
        
    if ($type) {
        // only replace the type and nothing else.
        $tag = preg_replace('/ type="(.*?)" /', 
            ' type="' . esc_attr($type) . '" ', 
            $tag);
    }
        
    return $tag;
}
```

This can be used for other types and only replaces the "type" and doesn't duplicate it etc.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/countup.js/2.0.0/countUp.min.js" id="countup-js"></script>`

becomes

`<script type="module" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/countup.js/2.0.0/countUp.min.js" id="countup-js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I want to address a specificity to Paul Naveda's answer.
Yes it works, but with this your basically losing any additional inline scripts.

What I mean is, when using [`wp_add_inline_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) function, which basically takes what you are giving it, and either add it just before or after the current 's handle:

> [*wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php:393*](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-scripts.php#L393) (github)

```php
$tag  = $translations . $cond_before . $before_handle;
$tag .= sprintf( "<script%s src='%s' id='%s-js'></script>\n", $this->type_attr, $src, esc_attr( $handle ) );
$tag .= $after_handle . $cond_after;
$tag = apply_filters( 'script_loader_tag', $tag, $handle, $src );
```

So by doing:

```php
$tag = '<script type="module" src="' . esc_url( $src ) . '"></script>';
```

You loose the before and after  tag.
To make sure you're not losing it, either use [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) (it's supposed to only be used for translating though)
or add those lines of codes:

```php
function add_type_attribute($tag, $handle, $src) {
    if ('your_handle_here' === $handle) {
        /** @var WP_Scripts $wp_scripts */
        global $wp_scripts;
        $before_handle = $wp_scripts->print_inline_script( $handle, 'before', false );
        $after_handle  = $wp_scripts->print_inline_script( $handle, 'after', false );
        if ( $before_handle ) {
            $before_handle = sprintf( "<script type='text/javascript' id='%s-js-before'>\n%s\n</script>\n", esc_attr( $handle ), $before_handle );
        }
        if ( $after_handle ) {
            $after_handle = sprintf( "<script type='text/javascript' id='%s-js-after'>\n%s\n</script>\n", esc_attr( $handle ), $after_handle );
        }
        $tag = $before_handle;
        $tag .= sprintf( "<script type='module' src='%s' id='%s-js'></script>\n", $src, esc_attr( $handle ));
        $tag .= $after_handle;
    }
    return $tag;
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_type_attribute' , 10, 3);
```

It keeps the before and after  and print it if present

Keep in mind this is still not perfect, because of `$translations` variable, but this is another approach if you are using [`wp_add_inline_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/)

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by @PaulNaveda, @peter and @zeldri

A small plugin demontrating JS modules support, including localization and inline scripts.

---

Content of wp-content/plugins/js-module-support-demo/js-module-support-demo.php

```php
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Javascript Module Support - Demo
Plugin URI: https://froger.me/
Description: Javascript Module Support - Demo
Version: 0.1
Author: Alexandre Froger
Author URI: https://froger.me/
*/

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------
 * Below is the main logic - it can be used in plugins or a theme
 * --------------------------------------------------------------- */

add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_type_attribute', 10, 3 );
function add_type_attribute( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    $type = wp_scripts()->get_data( $handle, 'type' );

    if ( $type && is_string( $type ) ) {
        $tag = str_replace( ' src=', 'type="' . esc_attr( $type ) . '" src=', $tag );
    }

    return $tag;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Below is the demo code - it adds the demo scripts (main, module, localization, inline)
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'demo_scripts', 10, 1 );
function demo_scripts() {
    $inline_script = '
        console.log(\'this is an inline script added to demo.js\');
    ';

    wp_enqueue_script( 'demo', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/demo.js', array(), false, true );
    wp_scripts()->add_data( 'demo', 'type', 'module' );
    wp_add_inline_script( 'demo', $inline_script );
    wp_localize_script( 'demo', 'LocalizationVar', array( 'key' => 'value' ) );
}
```

Content of `wp-content/plugins/js-module-support-demo/js/demo.js`

```js
import moduleVar from './module.js'

console.log(moduleVar);
console.log(window.LocalizationVar);
```

Content of `wp-content/plugins/js-module-support-demo/js/module.js`

```js
const moduleVar = 'This is a variable from module.js';

export default moduleVar;
```

---

Upon execution of the full demo code, the following is seen in the console:

```
this is an inline script added to demo.js
This is a variable from module.js
{"key":"value"}
```