# Why is my script_loader_tag hook not actually changing the type of script?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress plugin, that appears as a metabox on the edit post page I'm writing which is supposed to call scripts of both custom HTML elements AND modules. However, when I view source, the scripts that need to appear as `type="module"` only appear as `type="text/javascript"`. My code is:

```
function meta_box_setup() {
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', __NAMESPACE__ . '\add_meta_box' );
    add_action( 'save_post', __NAMESPACE__ . '\save_meta_box_data', 10, 2 );

    wp_register_script('Module1','/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/js/model/module1.js');
    wp_register_script('Module2','/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/js/module2.js', array('Module1'));
    wp_register_script('Module3','/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/js/Controller/module3.js', array('Module1','Module2'));
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function () {
        wp_enqueue_script('Module1');
        wp_enqueue_script('Module2');
        wp_enqueue_script('Module3');
    });
    add_filter('script_loader_tag', 
        function ($tag, $handle, $src) {
            if (( 'Module3' !== $handle ) || ('Module1' !== $handle) || ('Module2' !== $handle)) {
                return $tag;
            }
            $tag = '<script type="module" src="' . $src . '"></script>';
            return $tag;
    }
    , 10, 3);


    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function () {
        error_log("inside the scripts callback");
        wp_enqueue_script('Element1','/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/js/element1.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('Element2','/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/js/element2.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('Element3','/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/js/element3.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('Element4','/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/js/element4.js');
    });
}
```

I tried to base my code off [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58931144/enqueue-javascript-with-type-module) but to no avail. How can I get the modules to show up as type='module'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your boolean logic for returning early should either use `&&`, or it should continue to use `||` but use that to change the tag:

```php
<?php
add_filter('script_loader_tag',
    function ($tag, $handle, $src) {
        if (('Module3' === $handle) || ('Module1' === $handle) || ('Module2' === $handle)) {
            $tag = '<script type="module" src="' . $src . '"></script>';
        }

        return $tag;
    }
    , 10, 3);
```